# HQL: Counting a child collection conditionally within a query

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, hql

I'm fairly inexperienced when it comes to HQL, so I was wondering if anyone can help me out on this. I have a relationship where Student has a OneToMany relationship with StudentCollege. I'm trying to write a query that finds each student who has made an application, and how many applications they've submitted. I have the following query written, but I am unsure if it's even close to what I should be doing.

```
select distinct new ReportVO (stu.id, stu.first_name, stu.last_name, stu.year, stu.school.school_name, sum(case when si.applied = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as numApplications) " +
                    "from StudentCollege as si join si.student as stu where stu.year <= 12 and stu.user.id = :userId and si.applied = 1 order by stu.last_name
```

When it runs the following exception is thrown:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [package.location.ReportVO] [select distinct new ReportVO (stu.id, stu.first_name, stu.last_name, stu.year, stu.school.school_name, sum(case when si.applied = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as numApplications) from package.location.StudentCollege as si join si.student as stu where stu.year <= 12 and stu.user.id = :userId and si.applied = 1 order by stu.last_name]
```

However I have a constructor for the VO object that takes in that same number of arguments, so I'm thinking the type returned from the **sum** is incorrect. I've also tried replacing **numApplications** with **Integer** and **Count**, but the same exception is thrown.

```
public ReportVO(int id, String firstName, String lastName, int year, String school, Integer numApplications)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are a missing a "group by" clause after the where clause.

```
select distinct new ReportVO (stu.id, stu.first_name, stu.last_name, stu.year, stu.school.school_name, sum(case when si.applied = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as numApplications) " +
                    "from StudentCollege as si join si.student as stu where stu.year <= 12 and stu.user.id = :userId and si.applied = 1 group by stu.id, stu.first_name, stu.last_name, stu.year, stu.school.school_name order by stu.last_name
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding the group by clause yielded the same exception and message - "Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class" I appreciate the idea though.